# Finding the relation between two dimensions in a multi-dimensional problem

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

I have a collection of data points. Each point has 6 dimensions (`x1, x2,...x6`). I want to find a relation between two dimension (e.g. `x1 vs x2`). What I have been doing so far is look for points where the other dimensions (`x3 to x6`) are relatively constant, by defining a band. This way I would get several groups of data points where only the two dimensions of interest would change.

I was wondering if there is a better way of analyzing the relationship between these two dimensions. I looked at PCA, but I have a feeling that it does not help me much. If I reduce the problem to two dimensions the axes are basically meaningless.

Can you guys give me some directions to look at?

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [canonical correlation analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation). It tries to find correlation between two sets of data. I guess you could adapt it to explore your data.

Comment: Yes, I just edited it, thx.

Comment: @debzsud You corrected the wrong "two", I fixed it all, and added link to wikipedia article. (my edit is pending approval at this moment)